# how to remove these usercreation forms instruction in django

Tags: python, django

```
class Driver_SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")
        model = User
        help_texts = {
            'username': None,
            'email': None,
            'password1': None,
            'password2': None,
        }
```

this is the code
i already use the help text none but not working properly
here is image of that

[image: how to remove password instructions]

Answer (score 4):

`password1` and `password2` aren't fields of the `User` model, so adding them to the `fields` list and trying to override the help texts in `Meta` doesn't do anything. **That only works when you want to override model fields.**

You should just redefine them at the top of your form, copying them from the `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm` and removing the help texts.

```
class DriverSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        strip=False,
    )
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        fields = ("username", "email")
```